# Python Flask returning with backslashes to JSON curl request

Tags: json, mongodb, curl, flask

I am getting the results from my mongoDB database and trying to send them as a JSON object through curl:

```
custos = customerDB.CustomerModel.find()

jsonCusto = []
for doc in custos:
temp = json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
jsonCusto.append(temp)
```

I print this before send and get:

```
'{"firstName": "Joshu", "lastName": "Wak", "creation": {"$date": 1414531609314}, "Cust_ID": 101, "streetNo": "3231", "_id": {"$oid": "54500a19d0f6120a0021c879"}, "email": "lolazo@cvn.com", "streetName": "washingoton"}'
```

but on the curl screen I get:

```
"{\"firstName\": \"Joshu\", \"lastName\": \"Wak\", \"creation\": {\"$date\": 1414531609314}, \"Cust_ID\": 101, \"streetNo\": \"3231\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"54500a19d0f6120a0021c879\"}, \"email\": \"lolazo@cvn.com\", \"streetName\": \"washingoton\"}
```

I tried about 10 combinations and cannot get it right. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: I read on Google that these are only 'visual', and do not actually exist in the variable value itself. Is this right? It doesnot happen to other websites though?

Comment: How are you *sending* `jsonCusto` to the client?  `jsonify(someKey=jsonCusto)` or something else?

Comment: I tried both jsonify(someKey=jsonCusto) and someKey=jsonCusto

Comment: `return someKey=jsonCusto` isn't valid Python - can you show us the part where you actually return the `jsonCusto` to the client?

Comment: I just return it with 'return Custo', is that wrong?

Comment: Is `Custo` the same as `jsonCusto` in your code snippet or is it something else?  If it is the same as `jsonCusto` what customizations have you made to Flask so it understands a list of strings is a single `application/json` response?

Comment: My *suspicion* is that you are double-encoding your JSON data (first with `json.dumps` in your code snippet here and then again before you return it to the client).

Comment: "[{\"firstName\": \"Alex\", \"middleName\": \"X\", \"lastName\": \"bunyc\", \"creation\": {\"$date\": 1414628193009}, \"streetNo\": \"323\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5451836114b6e46b4b4a3b98\"}, \"email\": \"DD@D\", \"streetName\": \"chicago\"}]"

Comment: The double quotes int he outermost layer are the problem. So how do I get rid of them?

PS. you think the looping might be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly are double-encoding your JSON.  Simply remove the `json.dumps` in your loop and only use it at the end:

```
custos = customerDB.CustomerModel.find()
jsonCusto = list(custos)
jsonText = json.dumps(jsonCusto, default=json_util.default)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same challenge. In my case I wrote some_schema.**dumps()** instead of some_schema.**dump()**

Below is the output of author_schema.**dumps()**:

```
@app.route('/authors', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    get_authors = Authors.query.all()
    author_schema = AuthorsSchema(many=True)
    authors= author_schema.dump(get_authors)
    return make_response(jsonify({"authors": authors}))
```

Output:

```
{
  "authors": "[{\"specialisation\": \"Joke Developer\", \"name\": \"Kaunda Ibn Ahmed\", \"id\": 1.0}, {\"specialisation\": \"History\", \"name\": \"Akademic Vuvuzela\", \"id\": 2.0}]"
}
```

Below is the output of author_schema.**dump()**:

```
@app.route('/authors', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    .....
    .....
    authors= author_schema.dump(get_authors)
    return make_response(jsonify({"authors": authors}))
```

Output:

```
{
  "authors": [
    {
      "id": 1.0,
      "name": "Kaunda Ibn Ahmed",
      "specialisation": "Joke Developer"
    },
    {
      "id": 2.0,
      "name": "Akademic Vuvuzela",
      "specialisation": "History"
    }
  ]
}
```